# Problems running command with parameters with path with spaces

Tags: windows, cmd

I need to run the command:

```
certmgr.exe -add MyCert.cer -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher
```

Now the problem I have is that certmgr.exe is not in my path.  I also don't want to add it to my path.

OK, I could of course, do:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0
```

The path to certmgr.exe is The Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0 path as above.

But I should be able to run the command using the full path to the executable.

So I tried the following:

```
>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\certmgr.exe" -add comodo.cer -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher
'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\certmgr.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

>"..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\certmgr.exe" -add comodo.cer -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher
'"..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\certmgr.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

>start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\certmgr.exe" -add comodo.cer -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher
The system cannot find the file -add.

>set THISPROG=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\certmgr.exe

>%THISPROG% -add comodo.cer -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

>"%THISPROG%" -add comodo.cer -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher
'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\certmgr.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How can I run the command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\certmgr.exe" -add comodo.cer -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher
```

without adding "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0 to my path?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? It was definitely working with the notepad example!! :0)

Comment: What output from `where /R C:\ certmgr.exe`? Or (the same) `dir /B /S C:\certmgr.exe`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
set THISPROG="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\certmgr.exe"
```

(Note the `""` around the path) then

```
%THISPROG% -add comodo.cer -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher
```

I can't seem to find the file you mention in my visual studio folder, but i did just test this format to open a file in notepad.

---

In my test, i had a file at `C:\a.txt` and i used ...

```
set AAA="C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
%AAA% C:\a.txt
```